# React Native styling input from ui kit to have a rounded border

Tags: javascript, user-interface, react-native, input

I am using an input component from the ui kit react native elements, and I am trying to style it to have a rounded shape with a border radius to no success.  The default input style is just a line like shown in this picture:
[image]

I am trying to get my input to look something like this, from the react native elements demo app:
[image]

I have tried various types of styling in order to get the input rounded, such as the following:

```
<Input 
   borderStyle= 'solid'
   borderColor= 'black'
   borderRadius='25'
   overflow="hidden"
   keyboardAppearance="dark"
   placeholder=""
   onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})}}
   value={this.state.message}
  />
```

However no changes seem to change the input from the default style.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have gotten a rounded text input to appear, however for some reason the straight line is still there and the text appears to far to the left in the input. Here is the updated code:

```
<Input
        containerStyle={{marginVertical: 10}}
        overflow="hidden"
        inputStyle={{ borderStyle: 'solid', marginLeft: -4,overflow: 'hidden', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'lightgrey', borderRadius: 25}}
        keyboardAppearance="dark"
        placeholder=""
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})}}
        value={this.state.message}
        />
```

And this is the result:
[image]

How do I get rid of that line and move the text cursor to the right?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use all those parameter inside style

```
<Input  
    style={{borderStyle: 'solid',borderColor: 'black', borderRadius: '25'}}
    overflow="hidden"
    keyboardAppearance="dark"
    placeholder=""
    onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})}}
    value={this.state.message}
/>
```

Comment: Nothing changed whenever I entered that code, is there some other type of styling that would need to be done? Or can it not change because it's from a ui kit?

Comment: Are you using NativeBase kit?

Comment: I am using react native elements, I kind of got it to work but still have some problems, please read my edited answer.  Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the styles in containerStyle instead. Like

```
<Input
    containerStyle={{ borderStyle: 'solid', overflow: 'hidden', marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'lightgrey', borderRadius: 25}}
    overflow="hidden"
    keyboardAppearance="dark"
    placeholder=""
    autoCorrect={false}
    onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})}}
    value={this.state.message}
    />
```

Hope it's helpful to someone.